# Chance Curve in Accuracy-vs-Rank Plots in matlab

Tags: machine-learning, matlab, information-retrieval, computer-vision

I'm working on an image classification problem where each test image (query image) is compared with a set of candidate images (of which several images are considered as "correct answers" or "relevant"). From this comparison, a similarity measure is computed. The candidates are sorted decreasingly based on their similarity to the query image. So, basically, we are generating a ranking such as the ones generated by search engines. To evaluate such systems, it's typical to use mean average precision (MAP) and precision-vs-recall plots. However, I came across something with which I'm not familiar, which is the rank-vs-identification plot. From its name, I assume that this plot shows the identification rate at each rank. My problem is how to compute the chance curve for such a plot. Specifically, I have the following piece of code, which was extracted from the code used to generated Figure 3 of the following paper:

http://crcv.ucf.edu/papers/cvpr2014/Resemblance_CVPR14.pdf

This code is for the chance curve only. I am hoping that someone would help me understand how the chance plot was generated and what the variables x and xMax stand for.

**%%A snippet of Matlab code:**

```
fSize = 15;
```

% Compute Chance
    xMax = 54;
     ranks = [1 2 3 4 5:5:xMax]';
     x = 8;% x value in the equation.
     c = ones(length(ranks),1); % the equation that calculates the chance     value 
  for r = 1 : length(ranks)
    if ranks(r) >= xMax; break; end
%     c(r) = 1 - (nchoosek(xMax-1,ranks(r)) / nchoosek(xMax,ranks(r)));
%     c(r) = 1 - (xMax - ranks(r))/xMax;
    c(r) = 1 - newc(xMax-ranks(r),x) / newc(xMax,x);
end

leg1 = {'Chance'};
figure(1);
semilogx(ranks,c,'linewidth',3,'color',[1,0,0]); set(gca,'FontSize',fSize);
hold on;
 psAll = zeros(length(ranks));
 figure(1); legend(leg1,'Location','SouthEast','FontSize',fSize); grid; xlim([1 1000])
 xlabel('Rank','FontSize',fSize,'FontWeight','bold'); ylabel('Identification Rate','FontSize',fSize,'FontWeight','bold');
  xMaxStr = num2str(xMax);
   set(gca,'XTick',[1 10 100 1000]);

**% newc function used in the above piece of code**

function res = newc(n,x)

res = n - x + 1 : 1 : n;
res = prod(res);